# When to use references in for loops?

Tags: for-loop, rust, reference

An example from the documentation about vectors:

```
let v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let third: &i32 = &v[2];
println!("The third element is {}", third);

match v.get(2) {
    Some(third) => println!("The third element is {}", third),
    None => println!("There is no third element."),
}
```

I can't see why `third` needs to be a reference. `let third: i32 = v[2]` seems to work just as well. What does making it a reference achieve?

Similarly:

```
let v = vec![100, 32, 57];
for i in &v {
    println!("{}", i);
}
```

why is it `in &v` instead of just `in v`?

Answer (score 3):

`let third: i32 = v[2]` works because `i32` implements `Copy` trait. They don't get moved out when indexing the vector, they get copied instead.

When you have a vector of non `Copy` type, it is a different story.

```rust
let v = vec![
    "1".to_string(),
    "2".to_string(),
    "3".to_string(),
    "4".to_string(),
    "5".to_string(),
];

let third = &v[2]; // This works
// let third = v[2]; // This doesn't work because String doesn't implement Copy
```

As for the second question about the loop, for loop is syntactic sugar for `IntoIterator` which moves and consumes.

So, when you need to use `v` after the loop, you don’t want to move it. You want to borrow it with `&v` or `v.iter()` instead.

```rust
let v = vec![100, 32, 57];
for i in &v { // borrow, not move
    println!("{}", i);
}
println!("{}", v[0]); // if v is moved above, this doesn't work
```